# ASP.NET MVC ScriptBundle adding jquery 2.0.2 even though 2.0.3 is specified

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, scriptbundle

When I run my application locally, the javascript references work as expected, but when I deploy it to our dev servers, it adds jquery 2.0.2 reference right before the 2.0.3 reference.

Why is it adding this?

I'm guessing it shouldn't interfere since it's loading first... anything in 2.0.3 should overwrite anything in the previous version, but it seems unnecessary.

Packages file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
<package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="jQuery" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="5.0.8" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Twitter.Bootstrap" version="3.0.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

BundleConfig:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js")
    .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js")
    .Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")
    .Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap-windows.js")
    .Include("~/Scripts/MyProject.js")
    );
```

Output when running locally:

```
<script src="/MyProject/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="/MyProject/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/MyProject/Scripts/bootstrap-windows.js"></script>
<script src="/MyProject/Scripts/MyProject.js"></script>
```

Output when on development server:

```
<script src="/MyProject/Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
<script src="/MyProject/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="/MyProject/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/MyProject/Scripts/bootstrap-windows.js"></script>
<script src="/MyProject/Scripts/MyProject.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be that `/MyProject/Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.js` is actually there, on the disk, on the development server? The `{version}` wildcard of `.Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js")` would then cause it to be included.

For more on bundling you may want to check out [Bundling and Minification on www.asp.net](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification).

Comment: When you deploy to the server its good practice to clean the destination location.

Comment: 2.0.2 was on the dev server, so it was getting picked up.

Our build script does have a delete all files in the deployment location, so there may be a permissions problem on those files, they've been there since early November.

I also verified that 2.0.2 is not in TFS, and not being dropped in the staging folder before deployment.